# How to authenticate Azure REST APIs to Service Bus with SAS

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to send a message to the Service Bus queue using the REST API provided in this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue

Do note that I cannot use the Azure Libraries for this task as there are non available that I know of for Service Now and I'm setting up the test trigger in Python to simulate the REST API calls that would be made from Service Now.

I had a similar question with regards to [storage queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217182/how-to-authenticate-azure-rest-apis-to-storage-queue-with-sas) and I've tried reusing the same solution however the Service Bus would respond with "Missing Authorization Header"
This is my code that uses the Authorization in the header:

```
import requests
api = f"https://{service_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queue}/messages?"
msg = """<QueueMessage>  
<MessageText>Testing 1234</MessageText>  
</QueueMessage>
"""
header = {
    "Authorization": f"SharedAccessSignature sr=https://{service_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queue}&sig={sig}&se={se}&skn={skn}",
    "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"
}
resp = requests.post(api, data=msg, headers=header)
print(resp)
print(resp.text)
print(resp.headers)
```

Here, `sig` is the primary key I got from the Service Bus's Queue under Shared Access Policy

`se` is the epoch time 2 years from now (w/o mili seconds)
`skn` is the name of the policy

The final response I get is

```
<Response [401]>

{'Content-Length': '0', 'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Date': 'Thu, 24 Feb 2022 09:27:17 GMT'}
```

If I post without the Auth in the header and use the solution in the highlighted question above,
This is the API structure BTW:
`f"https://{service_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queue}/messages?sig={sig}&se={se}&skn={skn}"`
I get this error:

```
<Error><Code>401</Code><Detail>MissingToken: The authorization header was not found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:<redacted>, SystemTracker:<redacted>.servicebus.windows.net:<redacted>/messages, Timestamp:2022-02-24T09:31:09</Detail></Error>
{'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Date': 'Thu, 24 Feb 2022 09:31:09 GMT'}
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this, any tips and suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are computing the shared access signature incorrectly. You can learn more about it [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token).

To generate SAS token using python, please see the code below which is taken from [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#python):

```
import time
import urllib
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

def get_auth_token(sb_name, eh_name, sas_name, sas_value):
    """
    Returns an authorization token dictionary 
    for making calls to Event Hubs REST API.
    """
    uri = urllib.parse.quote_plus("https://{}.servicebus.windows.net/{}" \
                                  .format(sb_name, eh_name))
    sas = sas_value.encode('utf-8')
    expiry = str(int(time.time() + 10000))
    string_to_sign = (uri + '\n' + expiry).encode('utf-8')
    signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(sas, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signed_hmac_sha256.digest()))
    return  {"sb_name": sb_name,
             "eh_name": eh_name,
             "token":'SharedAccessSignature sr={}&sig={}&se={}&skn={}' \
                     .format(uri, signature, expiry, sas_name)
            }
```